# Algorithm for finding an embedding of a cover diagram

Tags: algorithms, graphs, partial-order, lattices

I am making some [notes on order theory](https://galenseilis.github.io/posts/notes-on-order-theory/) for my own self study (and certainly anyone else that wants to read them).

I'm impressed with what [`mermaid`](https://mermaid.js.org/) can do out of the box, but unfortunately I will need to make directed network diagrams with certain choices of embedding rules. Mermaid will choose an embedding that is aesthetically pleasing, but does not follow the needed rules. I have a similar issue with [`graphviz`](https://github.com/xflr6/graphviz), although I have not explored [`DOT`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOT_(graph_description_language)) itself all that thoroughly.

What I would like is an algorithm to find an embedding (i.e. in this case x,y values on the Cartesian plane) that satisfies the constraints of a cover diagram. The input would be the pairs that make up the partial order relation, which can be given in a set (i.e. iterable but not given in any particular order). Or you can assume they are in a list in topological order, if that is convenient.

> A cover diagram is a drawing of the directed graph representing a cover relation such that the edges are cover pairs . Edges are drawn in such a way that x is below y (in the graph embedding) and the edge is y-monotone.

Now to be clear, I am not asking for an implementation. I would like to take the algorithm and use it with different tools such as [`networkx`](https://networkx.org/), [`tikz`](https://tikz.net/), or other tools as I find interesting/useful. It may be more generally useful to users of this site if it isn't tool-specific anyway.